# delayed job solution with google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub

My application picks up queued messages from google cloud pubsub and processes the task. The worker app is hosted with google app engine as well (Node.js). Worker app gets into trouble due to rate limiting imposed by the 3rd party applications. Is there any off the shelf solution to run delayed job within google cloud platform?

Thanks !

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is something equivalent to Amazon's SQS delay queue (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html). Is there anything similar in google cloud platform?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to circle back and update what I ended up doing. Using Google pubsub, pull subscription, NO auto ack. Send the message with an attribute timer, pull one or how many ever message at a time, check if the timer is reached. If reached, ack the message. Else, just ignore the message processing at the subscriber side. By not acknowledging the message that contain future time, pubsub will try to deliver that same message over and over in whatever interval you prefer. This works perfect, no need for any other solution like kue.js etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [The delay package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/delay) which is currently available for Go language given in Google Cloud Platform..

As stated in the given documentation, package delay provides a way to execute code outside the scope of a user request by using the [taskqueue API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/reference).

To declare a function that may be executed later, call `Func` in a top-level assignment context, passing it an arbitrary string key and a function whose first argument is of type `context.Context`.

```
var laterFunc = delay.Func("key", myFunc)
```

It is also possible to use a function literal.

```
var laterFunc = delay.Func("key", func(c context.Context, x string) {
// ...
})
```

For a complete list of the contents of the delay package for Go, please go through [The delay package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/delay).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There are similar solutions in NodeJs world as well (https://github.com/Automattic/kue). But I expected a fully managed service like SQS..

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Tasks API could be used with Cloud Function to create scheduled tasks that later push messages to the App Engine app:
[image]

More info: https://blog.doit-intl.com/deduplication-delayed-messaging-and-fifo-with-pub-sub-b4b4373820a9